# Prove that there is a linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $\text{ker}(T) = U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U \subseteq V$ a sub-space of V.
How can I prove that there is a linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $\text{ker}(T) = U$?
(Please suggest answers; not hints.)

**Attempt** 
I tried $T_1(v) = 0$ for $v\in U$ and $T_1(v) = w$ for $v\not\in U$ and a chosen $w\in V$ yet $w\not\in U$.
But this isn't necessarily a linear map since $u, v \in U$ yet it might be that $u + v \not\in U$.
And I got stuck.

Comment: There is a vague hint there with no final answer.

Comment: There is a very clear hint. Try to make use of the hint.  This site only assists you in the process of finding answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We make use of the following theorem ("extending a map by linearity"):

> Let $V$, $W$ be vector spaces.
> Let $\beta$ be a basis of $V$. For any map $f:\beta\to W$,
> there exists a unique linear map $T:V\to W$ such that $T(x)=f(x)$ for any $x\in\beta$.

Then we can simply choose a basis $\alpha$ for $U$ and extend it to a basis $\beta$ of $V$.
Choose $f:\beta\to V$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in \alpha$ and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \beta\setminus\alpha$.
Then there exists linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $T(U)=\{0\}$.
The fact that $\text{ker}(T)\le U$ can be proved easily by noticing that $\beta\setminus\alpha$ is linearly independent.

Comment: So my attempt was somewhat correct because for $u, v \in U$ it must be that $u + v \in U$ thanks to closure under addition in vector spaces.

Comment: @NitayStack Actually, I just realized that in your statement you didn't assume that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then the statement is obviously false because the kernel of a linear map must be a subspace. If $U$ is required to be a subspace, then $u+v\in U$ for any $u,v\in U$ is also trivial.

Comment: For some reason this answer is downvoted...

Comment: It is a sub-space, sorry, I will correct my question.